# Upgrading to 4.6.0-rc6 kernel fixed my flickering screen issue but now WiFi doesn't work (Dell XPS 13)

Tags: wireless, kernel, dell, broadcom

I have a 2016 Dell XPS 13 (FullHD display, i5 version). It has a Broadcom wifi module (BCM4350) which you might know has pretty terrible Linux support. However, it is supported by the Linux kernel from 4.4.+ so I installed Ubuntu 16.04 to get a 4.4.+ kernel. That led to some flickering screen issues which I think is related to the Skylake processor.

Eventually I decided to upgrade the kernel by downloading the .deb files from Ubuntu. I downloaded 4.6.0-rc6 and now the flickering screen issues are all gone but I have no wifi connection anymore...

Output from running `lspci -vnn -d 14e4:` below:

```
3a:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0021]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 283
    Memory at dc400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Memory at dc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfcmac
```

Worth noticing is that it actually did work the first time I booted the laptop. I then put it into suspend mode, opened it up and now it doesn't work at all (even after a cold reboot)

Any help is appreciated (either fixing the flickering screen on 4.4 or fixing Wifi on 4.6)!

Comment: Have you tried installing the b43 installer and then running sudo modprobe b43 that is what i had to do to my sons laptop who has the same wireless card that you do.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

It will restart your network manager.