# Kernel 4.5.3 WIFI issues?

Tags: wireless, kernel, dell, 16.04

Specs: Dell XPS 15 9550, Ubuntu 16.04

Kernel 4.5.2 worked great for me.

After upgrading to kernel 4.5.3, my WIFI is spotty at best. It was instantly noticeable.

Many times, it's like my network adapters' drivers aren't being loaded. I need to reboot a few times.

Looks like other people might be experiencing similar problems with kernel 4.6.RCx

[Upgrading to 4.6.0-rc6 kernel fixed my flickering screen issue but now WiFi doesn't work (Dell XPS 13)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763912/upgrading-to-4-6-0-rc6-kernel-fixed-my-flickering-screen-issue-but-now-wifi-does)

It is strange that sometimes the drivers will load fine for me.

Any ideas?

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [1028:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
```

EDIT: This is fixed in kernel 4.6

Comment: Non-Ubuntu kernels are off-topic.

Comment: Where did you find the 4.5.3 kernel to install? From Ubuntu or elsewhere? Here, perhaps? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.3-wily/

Comment: I used the one listed in your comment. from the ppa mainline.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless adapter from the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Answer (score 0):

Small comment: I have the same problem on 4.5.0 kernel and XPS 9350. Still didn't find a solution. However, probably you don't need to reboot the whole system.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

should do the trick (as also proposed in the aforementioned question). It is although still annoying.